# MVC Controller override action does not get called in runtime loaded assembly

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, overriding

I have a controller that I want to override using an assembly that is loaded at runtime (Plugin). Project runs fine only does the override action "Print" never get called.

Controller

```
public class PrintController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public PrintController(ILogger logger)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
    }

    public virtual ActionResult Print(int id)
    {
    ...
    return File(bytes, "application/pdf", "Printout.pdf");
    }
}
```

MyCustomAssembly.dll that is loaded at runtime:

```
public class CustomPrintController : PrintController
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public CustomPrintController(ILogger logger) : base (logger)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
    }

    public override ActionResult Print(int id)
    {
        Do somthing else...
        return File(bytes, "application/pdf", "Printout.pdf");
    }
```

Runtime assembly is loaded the following way:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(PluginManager), "Initialize")]
....

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("MyCustomAssembly.dll");
        BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly(assembly);
    }
```

Any idea why the override action Print() does not get called?

Is it even possible to override a Controller actionresult?

Comment: Are you sure that the CustomPrintController is used by the request?

Comment: well it's called `CustomPrintController`, what happens when you navigate to `.../CustomPrint`?

Comment: this is a shot in the dark, but check your route configs, and make sure the controller is actually able to be hit

Comment: @MikeSW The virtual ActionResult Print() is called fine. Only I want it to be overridden by the CustomPrintController ActionResult Print().

Comment: @Jonesy I do not want to navigate to /CustomPrint. The application should stay the same and navigate to /Print. But the Print actionresult from /CustomPrintController should override the virtual Print method from the PrintController.